View conversion to PDF, fails every time
I'm currently working on my first Swift project and I'm encountering some issues. Yesterday, I was able to solve a problem through the forum, and now I'm facing a new one:
I want the user to be able to convert a recipe into a PDF. To do this, I want to convert the view that displays the recipe directly into a PDF.
When I start the simulator and click on a saved recipe from the database, the recipe is first displayed in the view. In the view, there is a button. However, when I click on it, I get an error message stating that this is not possible. Here is the error message:

SwiftUI/NavigationStackCore_UIKit.swift:15: Fatal error: No interface idiom was found when creating the navigation stack.

This is my code from the view:
//
//  RecipeView.swift
//  GourmetGenie
//
//  Created by Vanessa Wettori on 30.05.24.
//

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
import PDFKit

@MainActor
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var pdfURL: URL?
    var id = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack{
                RecipeView(id: id)
                Button("Generate PDF") {
                    pdfURL = generatePDF()
                }
                .padding()
                if let pdfURL = pdfURL {
                    ShareLink("Export PDF", item: pdfURL)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func generatePDF() -> URL {
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content:RecipeView(id: id))
        
        let url = URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: "generatedPDF.pdf")
        
        renderer.render { size, context in
            var pdfDimension = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
            
            guard let pdf = CGContext(url as CFURL, mediaBox: &pdfDimension, nil) else {
                return
            }
            pdf.beginPDFPage(nil)
            context(pdf)
            pdf.endPDFPage()
            pdf.closePDF()
        }
        
        return url
    }
}

@MainActor
struct RecipeView: View {
    @Query(sort: \Recipe.title) var recipes: [Recipe]
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @State private var isShowingEditRecipeView = false
    @State private var numberSchritt = 0
    var id = ""
    @State private var pdfURL: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(recipes, id: \.self) { recipe in
                        if (recipe.id == id){
                            Text(recipe.title)
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                            Text("")
                            Text("Zutaten:")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                            ForEach(recipe.amount.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                                Text("• \(recipe.amount[index]) \(recipe.ingredients[index])")
                            }
                            Text("")
                            ForEach(recipe.steps, id: \.self) { step in
                                Text("Schritt \(numberSchritt)")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                Text("• \(step)")
                                    .onAppear {
                                        numberSchritt += 1
                                    }
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func increaseNumber(){
        numberSchritt = numberSchritt + 1
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView(id: "")
        .modelContainer(for: Recipe.self)
}


Some explaining to my code: I pass the ID from the MainView to the RecipeView. In the RecipeView I search for the specific object. I know there are better solutions, to do that, but this was the only that worked for me. I don't want to change that.
Due to the error, I thought it was related to the NavigationView inside of RecipeView. I commented it out, and then I got this message:

Set a .modelContext in view's environment to use Query

Honestly I don't know, what I can do, to fix that. I know there are other questions on this topic, but they do not contain any error messages.
Edit: I have now updated my code to the latest standards. Sorry if my code quality is bad and there are mistakes in my code. I am just trying to get it to work, somehow.

Try switching to NavigationStack unless you have a really good specific reason there is no excuse for using API s that are so old. You also only need 1 for your entire app unless there are very specific reasons such as tab bar or sheets

@loremipsum Thanks  I just changed it back. At the beginning of this error, I had NavigationStack. Then I got the error and tried everything to fix that. So I changed NavigationStack to NavigationView. I will edit my question

You also only need 1 NavigationStack. Interface idiom errors usually replace to the idioms in Build Settings you might have unintentionally messed up the Build Settings. Create a new project and go through them 1x1 and adjust any changes you might have made.

@loremipsum okay thank you. You are right, I have my Navigationstack in the overview. I now deleted it from the RecipeView. But then I get the second Error with Set a .modelContext in view's environment to use Query

That version of modelContainer is known to cause issues in preview. If you search for the error you’ll find a few examples on how to overcome it. Usually you can create a static shared version or create the container on init of a wrapper and then inject.

One information in advance: ImageRenderer does not render ScrollView/List etc. You would need to wrap VStack in a separate view
